# remove item from list according to item's special attribute

Tags: python, list

I have a list composed with my defined items, each of which has a attribute `.name`

```
t = [item1, item2]
```

I want to remove item from the t list according to their attribute `.name`, like remove() or pop() methods. Maybe I can do something like:

```
t.remove(item.name=="Removed me")
```

Maybe I don't need to go through the whole list to filter out the item needed to be removed.

Answer (score 11):

List comprehension works well for this kind of stuff

```
t = [i for i in t if i.name!="Remove me"]
```

Indeed, as commented, it creates a new list

Comment: Note that it replaces the list object, which may or may not be acceptable in any given usecase.