# Python: removing objects from a list by attribute value

Tags: python, list, object

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, name, att1, att2):
        ...

myList = [MyClass("p1", 1, 1), MyClass("p2", 0, 0), MyClass("p3", 0, 1)]
```

Now I want to remove every object from myList if its att2 == 1.

Comment: You will need to know the instance variable name associated with att2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [remove item from list according to item's special attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33995906/remove-item-from-list-according-to-items-special-attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than removing the class instance from the list, construct a new list (list comprehension) that excludes unwanted classes. For example:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, name, att1, att2):
        self._name = name
        self._att1 = att1
        self._att2 = att2
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self._name=}, {self._att1=}, {self._att2=}'

myList = [MyClass("p1", 1, 1), MyClass("p2", 0, 0), MyClass("p3", 0, 1)]

myList = [c for c in myList if c._att2 != 1]

print(myList)
```

**Output:**

```
[self._name='p2', self._att1=0, self._att2=0]
```

Comment: Nice usage of the `=` format specifier! That being said, I think the `__repr__` implementation adds multiple additional concepts that might be confusing for beginners.

Comment: @fsimonjetz Force of habit. I **always** add a repr to any class that I devise and I would recommend that everyone does so as a matter of course. But that's my opinion which is not held in high esteem by the usual pedants in this forum